# Error Starting plutus-playground-client

Tags: plutus, plutus-playground, nix

I'm having error running the plutus-playground-client. Not sure where to look, here is the complete error log. Any suggestions on how to fix?

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/nix/store/gi44n1z2xslwsd417sigxsxgr6sxp9ff-nodejs-14.15.4/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/nix/store/gi44n1z2xslwsd417sigxsxgr6sxp9ff-nodejs-14.15.4/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.10
3 info using node@v14.15.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle plutus-playground-client@1.0.0~prestart: plutus-playground-client@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle plutus-playground-client@1.0.0~start: plutus-playground-client@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle plutus-playground-client@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle plutus-playground-client@1.0.0~start: PATH: /nix/store/gi44n1z2xslwsd417sigxsxgr6sxp9ff-nodejs-14.15.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_module>9 verbose lifecycle plutus-playground-client@1.0.0~start: CWD: /mnt/c/blockchain/cardano/plutus/plutus-playground-client
10 silly lifecycle plutus-playground-client@1.0.0~start: Args: [
10 silly lifecycle   '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'npm install && plutus-playground-generate-purs && npm run purs:compile && npm run webpack:server'
10 silly lifecycle ]
11 silly lifecycle plutus-playground-client@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle plutus-playground-client@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: plutus-playground-client@1.0.0 start: `npm install && plutus-playground-generate-purs && npm run purs:compile && npm run webpack:se>13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (/nix/store/gi44n1z2xslwsd417sigxsxgr6sxp9ff-nodejs-14.15.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycl>13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (/nix/store/gi44n1z2xslwsd417sigxsxgr6sxp9ff-nodejs-14.15.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycl>13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid plutus-playground-client@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /mnt/c/blockchain/cardano/plutus/plutus-playground-client
16 verbose Linux 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2
17 verbose argv "/nix/store/gi44n1z2xslwsd417sigxsxgr6sxp9ff-nodejs-14.15.4/bin/node" "/nix/store/gi44n1z2xslwsd417sigxsxgr6sxp9ff-nodejs-14.15.4/bin/npm" >18 verbose node v14.15.4
19 verbose npm  v6.14.10
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error plutus-playground-client@1.0.0 start: `npm install && plutus-playground-generate-purs && npm run purs:compile && npm run webpack:server`
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the plutus-playground-client@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

[image]

Comment: did you find the fix for this? I'm also facing the same issue.

Comment: How are you running it? Can you add more details please?

Answer (score 0):

**are u on the correct git commit?**

**did you start the server first?**

in the terminal, before entering to nix-shell do this to go to the correct git commit:
in the plutus-apps directory:

> git checkout 41149926c108c71831cfe8d244c83b0ee4bf5c8a

then
3. At top of this repo

> nix-build -A plutus-playground.server

4. Enter

> nix-shell

only then start the server

> cd plutus-playground-client

> plutus-playground-server

Wait for server to start, it'll log "Interpreter ready"
5. In second terminal at top of this repo, enter

> nix-shell
> cd plutus-playground-client
> npm run start
> Wait for the client to start, it'll log "webpack compiled with …”

6. In web browser, navigate to url https://localhost:8009/ (need to accept that ssl certificate is invalid)

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].