# First time compiling sample Plutus code in local Plutus Playground failed. Can't figure out why

Tags: plutus-playground

I've been a mainframe programmer my for decades.  Never developed on small server platforms. So the biggest challenge I'm having is dealing with the nerve wracking OS setup, Github cloning, server building, nix running craziness,  etc etc etc

These are the steps I accomplished leading up to my Failed Compile.

I followed The Plutus Playground Local Instance Instructions in the Plutus Env: Setup Starter Pack

1 Installed WSL (Ubuntu)   (couldn't get git to work until I did this.) Tried multiple thing. But only this worked.

then:

1. Download the plutus-apps repository: git clone https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps
   **COMPLETED**
2. Go to the latest commit of the repository: git checkout `41149926c108c71831cfe8d244c83b0ee4bf5c8a`
   **COMPLETED**
3. At top of this repo, `nix-build -A plutus-playground.server`
   **COMPLETED**

[image: This ran ALL night, went to bed and arrived to this in the morning]

4 Enter nix-shell then:      This ran literally all day and finished at the $prompt
[image]         **COMPLETED**

after nix-shell build stopped entered these two cmnds:

```
[nix-shell:~/plutus-apps]$ cd plutus-playground-client
[nix-shell:~/plutus-apps/plutus-playground-client]$ npm run start
```

[image: That ran a little while and ended with]  **COMPLETED**

I then navigated to localhost in browser which loaded the demo code to be compiled.
I hit the compile button , it displayed a Compilation Failed message and display the following errors in the Linux Command window:
[image]  **FAILED**

Comment: "This ran literally all day and finished at the $prompt", did you add the IOG caches to your nix configuration? That could explain why it built so much.

Comment: No, I saw mention of that after the fact in the week #1 Exercises.

Comment: No, I saw mention of that after the fact in the week #1 Exercises.   I figured at some point I should go back and do that.  It def should've been in the Plutus Env: Setup Starter Pack  instructions, it would've saved me a lot of time.   I have no choice but to push through all the apps I don't know (Linux, Nix, Haskell etc and learn on the fly through trial and error.     Thanks man.

Comment: FYI, I answered another question that's similar but not the same here that shows some details of a new tool I created that's a little less convoluted. It uses the power of nix to abstract away a lot of the ugliness. https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/6464/382

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notwithstanding the value/importance of cache issue pointed out by @angerman, the cause of the main question of your OP (i.e., the error on port 8080) appears to be that you started the client on 8009, but didn't show any steps for starting the server.

Open a second terminal session, enter the nix-shell, and start the server, and you should be set.

Comment: Thanks, this is great.  I see that I missed that step on the Setup Starter Pack.   Can I ask another quick question?       Cache setup says to update /etc/nix/nix.conf      Where is the /etc folder?   I haven't been able to locate it.   Do I have to create it?  If so what folder do I create it in.

Answer (score 0):

You should find the necessary `etc/` folder from your `root` directory.
In a terminal, you can do the following from anywhere to get there.

:~/plutus-apps$ `cd /`

bring you to this prompt...

:/$

that is your root dir/path (/) prompt

now;

:/$ `ls`

...and you should see something like this...

bin   dev  home  lib32  libx32      media  nix  proc  run   snap  sys  usr

boot  etc  lib   lib64  lost+found  mnt    opt  root  sbin  srv   tmp  var

Note the `etc/` dir.
Now that you know where it is, from here just change to the etc/ directory.
If you need to make a nix folder, simply use the mkdir command.

I am not sure how comfortable you are in the bash shell. If you are, here is a handy concatenated line to mkdir and create a nix.conf file at the same time:

```
sudo mkdir folder && sudo touch $_/file.txt
```

or -> sudo mkdir etc/nix/ && sudo touch $_/nix.conf

I hope that helps you out with this. Good luck!

Comment: This my friend is excellent!!  Thank you so much