# nix-build -A plutus-playground.client Error

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

I am part of cohort 3 and setting up on Mac OS also (Big Sur); I am following the notes here:https://docs.plutus-community.com/docs/setup/MacOS.html

Was able to complete Step 9 (build library). But on Step 10 I get this error:
attribute 'plutus-playground' in selection path 'plutus-playground.client' not found

I tried suggestions in other threads (such as edits to nix.conf). And continuing to fishing around. Meanwhile trying to see if anyone else crossed this chasm....

Comment: You could try my simplified setup repo/instructions here: https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/6464/382

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Answer (score 0):

Try building the PAB library as stated in the [README](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps):

```
cd .../plutus-apps
nix build -f default.nix plutus-apps.haskell.packages.plutus-pab.components.library
nix-shell
cd plutus-playground-client
plutus-playground-server
```

That worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Unfortunately I still get a (similar) errors:

error: attribute 'plutus-apps' in selection path 'plutus-apps.haskell.packages.plutus-playground-server' not found

error: attribute 'plutus-apps' in selection path 'plutus-apps.haskell.packages.plutus-playground-client' not found

Assume you tried on Big Sur also?

Comment: @Siva No I am currently running on Monterey. In the tutorial it states to clone https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus.git but that should be updated to https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps.git. Have you tried with this repo?

Comment: Ok; I followed this link:
https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/6380/plutus-playground-client-crashes-on-intel-mac-big-sur

After running for nearly 12 hours and after countless Warnings and Errors, it finally completed. And I enter the Plutus Pioneers Shell Tool welcome message. I am also able to access docs at/localhost:8009/doc. And cardano-cli query tip --testnet-magic 1097911063 works fine. 
So something is working! I am sure to find land mines as I go thru rest of pre-work.

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Comment: So glad our improved setup heped you @Siva